# How to perform multi auth in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to perform multi auth in my Laravel project. Initially I put it for user, then token is generated and its working fine. When I add employee too, then token is not generated for employee. When I remove for users and now employee is working but combinly both are not working.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
        //'provider' => 'employees'
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        //'provider' => 'employees'
    ],
    'employees' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'employees',
    ],
],
```

Can anyone please provide me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your auth.php file add providers in providers array for defined guards.

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
            //'provider' => 'employees'
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            //'provider' => 'employees'
        ],
        'employees' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'employees',
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'employees' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Employees::class,
    ],

],
```

If your as using 2 different model for authentication do like above. If you are using the same model to authenticate based on user role give the same model for employees and user.

create Route for employees login.

```
Route::get('/employee/login','Auth\EmployeeLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('employee.login');
Route::post('/employee/login','Auth\EmployeeLoginController@login')->name('employee.login.submit');
```

create EmployeeLoginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;

    class EmployeeLoginController extends Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest:employee');
        }

        public function showLoginForm()
        {
            return view('auth.employee-login');
        }

        public function login(Request $request)
        {
            // Validate the form data
            $this->validate($request, [
                'email'   => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required|min:6'
            ]);

            // Attempt to log the user in
            if (Auth::guard('employee')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
                // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
                return redirect()->intended(route('employee.Product.list'));
            }

            // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
            return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email'));
        }
    }
```

if you are using the 2 different model do like above. If you are using the same model to authenticate based on role just add the following check by role in the attempt method

```
attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'role' => 'employee'], $request->remember))
```

then in your app\Exception folder add the modify the unauthenticated methode in handler.php file

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)

```
 {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        $guard = array_get($exception->guards(),0);

        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin':
                $login = 'admin.login';
                break;
            case 'employee':
                $login = 'employee.login';
                break;
            default:
                $login = 'login';
                break;
        }
        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }
```

here actually you are $login variable is being used to redirect to the url you want if the user is not authenticated.

and last in your app\middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php file remove the handle methode and add the following.

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin':
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect()->route('admin.index');
                }
                break;

            case 'employee':
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect()->route('employee.dashboard');
                }
                break;

            default:
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect('/');
                }
                break;
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Here you are redirecting the user if they are authenticated.

for better understanding check this video.This works in both 5.3 and 5.4 It will help you to understand how all these works.

[Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKRLrJXNN4M)